# Android: AnimationDrawable Not working with Runnable

Tags: android, runnable, android-handler

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
   public static Runnable StartRun;
   private ImageView Player;

   protected void onCreate(){
   ...
   Player = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgStart);
   StartRun = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Player.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loadanimation); //XML animationlist
            AnimationDrawable frameanimation = (AnimationDrawable)
                                            Player.getBackground();
            frameanimation.start(); 

        }
    };
  }

}
```

```
public class RadioPlayer extends Service{
    Handler handle;

     public void onCreate(){
         handle = new Handler();
     }

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handle.post(MainActivity.StartRun);

    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(ACTION_PLAY, false)) {
        play();
    }
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
 }
```

I have tested the AnimationDrawable section of code directly in the onCreate(), so it does work.
I have used Logcat to confirm that the StartRun, run() is getting called, & i have also tried to define the imageview from inside the method as not to use global like it is at the moment.

Still, no cigar. Can anyone help?

UPDATE:
it would seem there is an underlying issue which is casuing this to error. i have successfully executed the animationDrawable code outside of the runnable thread, i.e directly on the activity (proof that the animation does work, however impracticable for myself), i have tryed to use localbroadcastReceiver, as well as handlers etc 
non of these non-direct-to-activity methods are successful and i have completly run out of ideas.

With lack of time, i have resorted to replacing the frame animation code with just a simple progressdialog. in some way it achieves the purpose, however it is a make-do settlement that will need to be addressed again in a few months. if anyone has the same issues and can shed any light on the subject, please comment/post

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start your animation on the onWindowFocusChanged method because it is the best place to know if the activity is visible to the user. The runnable in your code is only for showing the animation I presume. Something like this should work:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {    
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);         
if (hasFocus)
{
   Player.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loadanimation); //XML animationlist
   AnimationDrawable frameanimation = (AnimationDrawable) Player.getBackground();
   frameanimation.start();
  }

 }
```

Comment: would this not require a change in activity? i'm using the service for a mediaplayer stream so the focus would never change as the user never leaves the mainactivity (or appear to anyway)

i know its not good to link questions here, but this is where i am coming from (& want to end up with such a result)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328328/android-frame-animation-on-imageview-from-service-using-inflator

Comment: @SimonAddicott it would require you to override windowFocusChanged on your activity and shift some animation code there especially .start().